# SyntaxError on heroku "??="

Tags: node.js, heroku

Trying to figure out how I can find the syntaxerror

```
  2021-11-16T01:21:45.288923+00:00 app[worker.1]: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??='
        2021-11-16T01:21:45.288923+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1001:16)
        2021-11-16T01:21:45.288923+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:27)
        2021-11-16T01:21:45.288924+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
        2021-11-16T01:21:45.288924+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
        2021-11-16T01:21:45.288924+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
        2021-11-16T01:21:45.288925+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
        2021-11-16T01:21:45.288925+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
        2021-11-16T01:21:45.397389+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
        2021-11-16T01:21:45.437943+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

Comment: `??=` means [Logical nullish assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment) and was added in ECMA2021. Make sure your enviroment support it.